# Visual Studio 2022 Cannot Update EDMX Entity Model from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

All of a sudden I cannot update the `.edmx` files I have in all of my projects in Visual Studio 2022. This is something I have done tons of times on various projects for years: open the `.edmx`, right click empty space, "Update Model from Database".

Now it brings up a dialog for choosing my data connection (the connection strings are already in the config files and have been for years). Then the dialog just closes with no errors at all. Happens for all projects and don't know where to go from here?

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. VS 2022 17.5.1.

Comment: @DanSiders Same version for me. Has it only just started happening?

Comment: Yep, just started happening.  We last were successful in updating the edmx on Friday last week.

Comment: We rolled back to VS 2022 17.3.1 and it is working now.  I have an active ticket in with Microsoft and will update here if I discover more information.

Answer (score 6):

I just experienced the same issue with Visual Studio 2022, and upon further investigation, I discovered that there are issues with VS2022 and .edmx from version 17.4 onwards.

Nevertheless, it appears that the development team behind VS2022 is already [aware](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-175-no-longer-allows-use-of-conn/10288655?q=%5BVisual%20Studio%202022%20version%2017.5%5D%20EF&sort=votes) of this issue and is expected to release a new version that addresses it. However, I was able to "fix" it temporarily by following the workaround mentioned in the link, which involved removing “MultipleActiveResultSets=True;” from the connection string in the app.config.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the bug report. It now also has my vote.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but things returned to normal after I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5.3.

Comment: Yes, this problem has been fixed on 15th of March.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has fixed this issue in the 17.5.5 version. I update mine and it worked! Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The good old solution to delete the `.edmx` file and then recreate it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already checked that you have the right version of VS2022, then you need to resolve any compilation issues in the project, then close Visual Studio and re-open it.
I just had the same problem (second time)... I can't recall where I read this advice, but it worked for me.